# how to insert an object in a vector of vector with c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Please Can I know how I get a problem when running this program.
This my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    std::vector< vector< Point > > tableau2;
    std::vector< Point >  Vpoint;
     ....
     .....
      Point rt(s->c.x, s->c.y, s->c.z);
      std::vector<Point> pp;
      pp=triangulateSphere(rt, s->r);
         for (int indice=0;indice<pp.size();indice++)
         { 
             Point p1=pp[indice];
             Vpoint.push_back(p1);
             tableau2[i].push_back(p1);// This the cause of poblem
        }
     .....
     ....
      }
```

I didn't get any error but I get a problem when I try to run it and this because of the instruction `tableau2[i].push_back(p1);`

Thank you for your help

Comment: `tableau2` is empty and you are accessing it out of bounds in the inner loop.

Comment: `tableau2[i]` is not defined, your outer vector is of size 0. Try declaring it with size: `...Point > > tableau2(size);`

Comment: how can I tell it is resolved please?

Answer (score 0):

Tableau2 is empty, so you trying to access its values crashes your program.

Also it is better to use

```
vector.at(index)
```

Instead of directly accessing values like in a C array, since the at() method as protection

Comment: The [] method also checks the boundaries... one is generally implemented by calling the other anyway.

Comment: I realy didn't understand what do you want to say